# How to request.user.is_authenticated() in views.py? Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to check if user is logged in from my views.py file. As depending if user is logged in it should return me different forms. But request.user.is_authenticated() or request.user.is_authenticated is not working, i always get True value.

My view:

```
def ContactsView(request):
    form_class = ContactForm_logged(request=request)
    form_class_nonlogged = ContactForm_nonlogged(request=request)

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = ContactForm_logged(data=request.POST, request = request)
        else:
            form = ContactForm_nonlogged(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
                , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
                , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            subjects = form.cleaned_data['subjects']
            subjects = dict(form.fields['subjects'].choices)[subjects]
            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('threeD/email/contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'subjects': subjects,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New message from " + contact_name,
                content,
                "Message - " + subjects + ' ',
                ['smart.3d.printing.facility@gmail.com'],
                headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
            )
            email.send()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message.")
            return redirect('/index/contacts/')

    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = ContactForm_logged(request=request)
        else:
            form = ContactForm_nonlogged()

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'threeD/contacts.html', {
            'form': form_class,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'threeD/contacts.html', {
            'form': form_class_nonlogged,
        })
```

And two of my forms:

```
class ContactForm_logged(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subjects = forms.ChoiceField(choices=emailsubjects)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(ContactForm_logged, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"

        if (self.request.user.first_name == '' or self.request.user.last_name ==''):
            self.fields['contact_name'].initial = 'Type your name here'
            self.fields['contact_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = False
        else:
            self.fields['contact_name'].initial = self.request.user.first_name
            self.fields['contact_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"

        if (self.request.user.profile.sdu_email == ''):
            if (self.request.user.email == ''):
                self.fields['contact_email'].initial = 'Type your email here'
                self.fields['contact_email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = False
            else:
                self.fields['contact_email'].initial = self.request.user.email
                self.fields['contact_email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        else:
            self.fields['contact_email'].initial = self.request.user.profile.sdu_email
            self.fields['contact_email'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

        self.fields['content'].label = "What do you want to say?"
        self.fields['content'].initial = "Dear, Smart 3D printing facility team, I like this WEB server very much, but ..."

        self.fields['subjects'].label = "Please, select the subject of your message"


class ContactForm_nonlogged(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subjects = forms.ChoiceField(choices=emailsubjects)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(ContactForm_nonlogged, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"

        self.fields['contact_name'].initial = 'Type your name here'

        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Your email:"

        self.fields['contact_email'].initial = 'Type your email here'

        self.fields['content'].label = "What do you want to say?"
        self.fields['content'].initial = "Dear, Smart 3D printing facility team, I like this WEB server very much, but ..."

        self.fields['subjects'].label = "Please, select the subject of your message"
```

The problem is that, whether i am logged in or am not i always get ContactForm_logged form back. And if i m not logged in than, getting ContactForm_logged form back i get an error, that "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'".
I read on forums that that could have happened if i call request.user.is_authenticated() wrong, but i have tried both request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_authenticated, both give me the same error :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note you should use `return render(request, 'threeD/contacts.html', {'form': form})` in your view. If you use the form *class*, then you will get a blank form in the template, so errors will not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line of your view method definition:

```
def ContactsView(request):
    form_class = ContactForm_logged(request=request)
```

Here you are creating an instance of `ContactForm_logged` class. This line will be executed every time the view method is called. So an instance of `ContactForm_logged` class will be created everytime, whether user is logged-in or not. Further, in the `__init__` method of `ContactForm_logged` class you are accessing `self.request.user.first_name`. So when the `ContactForm_logged` instance is being initialized for unauthenticated requests it is raising the error: "*'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'*"

Comment: Good spot! The first two lines should be removed entirely. They are only used in the `return render()` line, and as I said in the comment above, you should be using `form` there, not the class. It would only make sense to use `form_class` if you then use `form = form_class(...)` later in your code instead of the if/else with `ContactForm_logged(...)` and `ContactForm_nonlogged(...)`. You can only do this if you change the nonlogged form to accept the `request` as well, or if you set the form kwargs as a separate step.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Ishan! I have added an extra if statement at the beginning of my view, like:     
if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_class = ContactForm_logged(request=request)
    else:
        form_class = ContactForm_nonlogged(request=request)

and am returning form_class. And it works now. Thank you, guys, for help!!!

Comment: Ou, now I see my problem... Thank you, @Alasdair. I have removed first two lines completely and changed my return to 'form': form, as u suggested above and it still works perfectly

Comment: Yes @Alasdair. ```form``` should be used in place of ```form_class``` and ```form_class_nonlogged``` in ```render``` method calls.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Django 1.10+, then you should use the property `request.user.is_authenticated`.

If you are using Django 1.9 or earlier, then you must use `request.user.is_authenticated()`. Using `request.user.is_authenticated` in Django 1.9 or earlier is a mistake which can cause sensitive data to be leaked, because it will always be evaluated as `True`.

If you are using the correct version and it is returning `True`, then that suggests you really are logged in.

Comment: Thank you, Alasdair, for your answer. I am using Django 1.9 version and in my views code i have request.user.is_authenticated(), but it still doesn't work. It returns me True all the time. And i am sure i am not logged in, since in my base template i am changing navigation bar using {% if user.is_authenticated %} ... {% endif %} and it is not getting changed (so i am sure i am not logged in), then i am accessing ContactsView and getting always True from my request.user.is_authenticated(), which leads to error :/

Comment: If `request.user.is_authenticated()` is True then I really think you are logged in. If the navigation bar says that you are not logged in, then that could be a bug in the navigation bar code.

Comment: If request.user.is_authenticated() is True you really are logged in. As Ishan says in his answer, the error is probably coming from the `form_class_nonlogged = ContactForm_nonlogged(request=request)`, not from inside the `if request.user.is_authenticated():` if statement. You can debug this yourself, by adding print statements or looking at the traceback.

Comment: Alasdair, how would you print to debug? Sorry, i m quite new in the topic, that's why i am asking silly Q :D

Comment: If you are using the Django development server and you add `print(request.user.is_authenticated())` to the top of your view, then you'll see the result in the window where `python manage.py runserver` is running.